# Serving Static & Media Files from AWS S3 Bucket with Django and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've set up a S3 bucket to serve to my Django application being deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It has full 'public' access and I can load using the respective urls as well as accompanying user IAM access:

Example:
https://bucketname.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/static/img/img-example.png

However when I try to serve the static media up using the below located in my settings.py it fails to retrieve the static files with the chrome console indicating a static url as:

https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/img/img-example.png (EER_ABORTED 404 (Not Found))

As you can see this is missing the 'eu-west-1' and the 'static' folder reference as shown in the working url. However, I can't seem to get 'django_s3_storage' to reflect this in the below code. As you can see I tried to specify the region in the url but this does not seem to be getting picked up.

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-1'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*******'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*******'

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static'),
    ]
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

S3_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucketname'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django_s3_storage.storage.StaticS3Storage"
AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC = S3_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{S3_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.{AWS_S3_REGION_NAME}.amazonaws.com' 
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
```

I tried to enforce the static url to retrieve from the appropriate region but this doesn't update in the chrome console, it remains the url as specified above.

Comment: `/static/` is missing because you did not provide it in `STATIC_URL`. Currently your `STATIC_URL` contains only domain name with no path. Please show template code where you reference this static file.

Comment: Have you made sure that your s3 bucket is set to public?